# Event handler seems to finish always after the main thread wait loop

Tags: c#, events, async-await

I am trying to load three speech grammars using `SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar)`.
The async loader raises a `LoadGrammarCompleted` event when the load is complete.
The `LoadGrammarCompleted` event handler sets a unique flag for each of the three grammars to indicate it has been loaded.

In my main thread, I want to loop and sleep until the load flags for all grammars are true.
I expect the debug messages from the waiting loop and the event handler to be interleaved as the grammars are loaded.
But instead, the loop always completes it 100-limit loops and THEN suddenly the event handler loaded messages are printed out.

What is going on? No matter how long I loop and wait, the LoadGrammarCompleted messages are always printed out (or logged) *after* the 100 loop messages have been logged or printed.

```
 // these flags are flipped by the LoadGrammarCompleted event handler
  public static bool
    G2Loaded = false, // false - no grammar has been loaded yet
    G3Loaded = false,
    G1Loaded = false;

// bind the event handler
x.LoadGrammarCompleted += LoadGrammarCompletedHandler;

// load all grammars async
 sre.LoadGrammarAsync(G1);
 sre.LoadGrammarAsync(G2);
 sre.LoadGrammarAsync(G3);
 
 // wait for all the grammars to load
    var grammarsLoaded = G1Loaded && G2Loaded && G3Loaded;
    var limit = 100;
    var count = 0;
    while (! grammarsLoaded && count < limit) {
      Thread.Sleep(20);
      grammarsLoaded = G1Loaded && G2Loaded && G3Loaded;
      count++;
      SendError($Waiting for async grammar loads. {count}");
    }

  // the event handler logs a message when the load operation is completed
  static void
    LoadGrammarCompletedHandler(object? sender, LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs e) {

    if (e.Grammar.Name == G1_Name) {
      G1Loaded = true;
      SendError($"Grammar is loaded. {e.Grammar.Name}");
    }

The output shows 100 loop messages and THEN the GrammarLoaded event messages. Why?

Output:
Waiting for async grammar loads 1
...
Waiting for async grammar loads 100
Grammar is loaded. helper
Grammar is loaded. sleep
```

But the output always shows no interleaving, even though the grammars are small and probably load instantly compared to the loop wait time. The output messages from the event handler (and the flags set by the event handler) seem to wait until the loop of 100 is complete.

What am I doing wrong? Could there be something going on with the visibility of the flags in the main loop thread and the event threads? I think maybe the main thread never sees the results of the flags that are set in the event handlers. That would explain why the main loop always runs to the 100 cycle limit. (But it would not affect the message output interleaving, I think.)

UPDATE:

Hans gave a clear answer that showed me that what I was expecting was wrong. But it also helped me to see what my real question should have been.

I have three grammars that I want to load in parallel. This is easily done by calling `sre.LoadGrammarAsync` three times in a row. Those methods start the processes and return to the calling thread "instantly."

But now how can I determine when the loads are complete? I registered the event handler on the same thread that calls `LoadGrammarAsync`, so the event handler is on the same thread that needs to wait for completion before proceeding. Hans pointed out that the calling thread cannot wait (loop with Sleep() as shown above) and set flags in the event handler at the same time.

FWIW, I tried using the synchronous `LoadGrammar(x)` methods with `Task.Run`, but that failed to load the grammars correctly (LoadGrammar is probably not thread safe).

What code can I use to make the thread wait until the async loads are complete? I am at a loss. Thank you.

Comment: A thread can do only one thing at a time.  It can execute a while loop or it can handle an event.  It can't do both.  Since you don't seem to have any practical use for async, or Thread.Sleep(), you might as well use LoadGrammer().

Comment: Thank you. Your answers are so clear. I was under the impression that the thread went somewhere else when I called Thread.Sleep(), kind of like DoEvents(). But I guess not. I will do as you suggest and use the synchronous load method. I can put them on different threads explicitly with Task.Run.

Comment: @HansPassant I modified the question to seek a way out of my dilemma. I want to load those grammars in parallel using ```LoadGrammarAsync``` because they will be big one day. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was (as Hans indirectly hinted) to use Task.Run in the main thread (t1) to call a method (on t2) that bound the event handlers and did the LoadGrammarAsync calls to load the grammars on a separate thread (t2).

Then execution returned to t1 where t1 looped to wait for the grammar-loaded flags to be set by the LoadGrammarCompleted event handlers.

When the LoadGrammarCompleted events were fired as each grammar loaded, those event handlers ran on the thread that bound the handlers (t2). The t2 event handlers could set flags that the main thread t1 was waiting on.

So, as Hans said, the t1 thread was waiting and looping, and the t2 thread was setting the flags as the grammars were loaded. Hopefully, this will help someone some day.